# Ember can't find find() method on model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ember can't seem to find the `findAll()` and `find()` methods I have implemented on my Property model.  Here are the errors I am getting:

```
TypeError: App.Property.findAll is not a function
```

and

```
Error: assertion failed: Expected App.Property to implement `find` for use in 'root.property' `deserialize`. Please implement the `find` method or overwrite `deserialize`.
```

My router is set up like this:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    showProperty: Ember.Route.transitionTo('property'),
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        home: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home', App.Property.findAll());
            }
        }),
        property: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/property/:property_id',
            connectOutlets: function(router, property) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('property', property);
            },
        }),
    })
});
```

And here is my model:

```
App.Property = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    address: null,
    address_2: null,
    city: null,
    state: null,
    zip_code: null,
    created_at: new Date(0),
    updated_at: new Date(0),
    find: function() {
        // ...
    },
    findAll: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Should those methods go on the Property model or should they go somewhere else?  Should I be override the `deserialize()` method instead of using `find()`?  But even if I use that workaround `findAll()` still wouldn't work and I would still get that first error.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `find` and `findAll` methods should be declared in `reopenClass`, not in `extend`, because you wants to define class methods, not instance methods.
For example:

```
App.Property = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    address: null,
    address_2: null,
    city: null,
    state: null,
    zip_code: null,
    created_at: new Date(0),
    updated_at: new Date(0)
});

App.Property.reopenClass({
    find: function() {
        // ...
    },
    findAll: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```